# Patient features for COVID Study

Tags: covid-19-datasets

The [USS Roosevelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Theodore_Roosevelt_%28CVN-71%29) COVID outbreak resulted [a significant fraction of asymptomatic carriers](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-usa-military-sympt/coronavirus-clue-most-cases-aboard-u-s-aircraft-carrier-are-symptom-free-idUSKCN21Y2GB) and provides a unique opportunity to gain insight into epidemiology  dynamics.

Given the well documented CVN-71 context:

- [4,865 sailors](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/navys-top-admiral-recommends-reinstating-captain-fired-virus/story?id=70242413&cid=clicksource_4380645_5_three_posts_card_related)
- 856 tested positive as of 24-April-2020

[Reuters indicates](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-usa-military-sympt/coronavirus-clue-most-cases-aboard-u-s-aircraft-carrier-are-symptom-free-idUSKCN21Y2GB):

> Roughly 60 percent of the over 600 sailors who tested positive so far
>   have not shown symptoms of COVID-19, the potentially lethal
>   respiratory disease caused by the coronavirus, the Navy says. The
>   service did not speculate about how many might later develop symptoms
>   or remain asymptomatic.

If a modified [Basili Weiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GQM) **Goal => Question => Feature** was applied to the Roosevelt population, where the goal is to understand the correlation between patient feature and likelihood of asymptomatic infection, what would features would be of interest?

For example:

- Gender
- Age
- Race
- Blood type
- height & weight

Although features are appreciated, a narrative featuring a sound thought-process will be favored.

Comment: @Fizz  Good reference: Graham Chiu's posting has many good suggestions such as smoking / co-morbidities